# Sophie's Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, history

My smart and beautiful daughter Sophie gave me this puzzle the other day... What do each of these letters and numbers stand for and why?

1. -4 + R = AOTC
2. -4 + PA = SR
3. 11 + P = OA
4. 17 + DOTM = CES
5. 18 + EDT = BOAPW
6. 18 + COPR = SA
7. 19 + POS = Z
8. 20 + TLP = AS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, with a big nod to @Strawberry who found the first connection which set this train in motion, I believe all of the bullet points here each take the form of:

> **Century** + **Initials of famous philosophical work** = **Famed content of said work**

The lines equate as follows:

> *1. -4 + R = AOTC*
>
>  **4th** century **BC** (hence the minus sign) + [**R**epublic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_(Plato)) (Plato) = [**A**llegory **O**f **T**he **C**ave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_cave)
>
>  *2. -4 + PA = SR*
>
>  **4th** century **BC** (hence the minus sign) + [**P**rior **A**nalytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_Analytics) (Aristotle) = [**S**yllogistic **R**easoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism)
>
>  *3. 11 + P = OA*
>
>  **11th** century (1077-78) + [**P**roslogion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proslogion) (Saint Anselm of Canterbury) = [**O**ntological **A**rgument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontological_argument)
>
>  *4. 17 + DOTM = CES*
>
>  **17th** century (1637) + [**D**iscourse **O**n **T**he **M**ethod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_on_the_Method) (René Descartes) = [**C**ogito **E**rgo **S**um](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cogito,_ergo_sum)
>
>  *5. 18 + EDT = BOAPW **(found by @Strawberry)***
>
>  **18th** century (1710) + [**E**ssaies **D**e **T**héodicée](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9odic%C3%A9e) (Gottfried Leibniz) = [**B**est **O**f **A**ll **P**ossible **W**orlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_of_all_possible_worlds)
>
>  *6. 18 + COPR = SA*
>
>   **18th** century (1781) + [**C**ritique **O**f **P**ure **R**eason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critique_of_Pure_Reason) (Immanuel Kant) = [**S**ynthetic **A**priori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critique_of_Pure_Reason#Synthetic_a_priori_judgments)
>
>  *7. 19 + POS = Z*
>
>  **19th** century (1807) + [**P**henomenology **O**f **S**pirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phenomenology_of_Spirit) (Georg Wilhelm Friedrich Hegel) = [**Z**eitgeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist#Hegel)
>
>  *8. 20 + TLP = AS*
>
>  **20th** century (1921) + [**T**ractatus **L**ogico-**P**hilosophicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus) (Ludwig Wittgenstein) = [**A**tomic **S**entence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_sentence#Philosophical_significance)

Also, I have the feeling this is called 'Sophie's Puzzle' since:

> PHILO**SOPHY** sounds a lot like her name! (Although the OP says in comments it is because the name '[Sophie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie#:%7E:text=Sophie%20(meaning%20%22wisdom%22),version%20of%20the%20name%20Sophia.)' means 'wisdom'...)

Comment: Almost, Number 2 is both wrong but very close, 6 is only wrong in the content but is almost right, 7 is only wrong in the content.

Comment: sbe 2 guvax ybtvp, sbe 6 lbh ner unys evtug, sbe 7 guvax tubfgf

Comment: Also Sophie means wisdom!

Comment: Come on, you're too kind. The *nod* should be a tiny one! You did all the legwork; I was nowhere near really !!! :-)

Comment: @Strawberry Without your insight I would in no way have gone down this path! :)

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Any closer to completeness now?

Comment: That insight was very impressive indeed I thought that it would be the hardest part of the puzzle to work out the formula.

Comment: Number 7 is still not correct.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 really?! I was so sure about that one second time round...

Comment: Oh my bad congratulations!!!

Comment: @Deepthinker101: You and Stiv are in agreement about the source of the puzzle's name.  Etymologically, philosophy means "love of wisdom" from philo (love) and sophis (wisdom).  Example [source](https://www.etymonline.com/word/philosophy), though honestly I recognized philo already (and you provided Sophis yourself above).  If you present this puzzle in the future, you could shoehorn a stronger link to Deepthinker's answer by explicitly stating that you love your daughter.

Answer (score 8):

> Just to observe that the phrase Best of All Possible Worlds occurs in Gottfried Leibniz's work of 1710 -  Essais de Théodicée...

Comment: Avpr bar pna lbh jbex bhg gur erfg?

Comment: Fgehttyvat jvgu gung :-(